# Service Temporarily Unavailable when System.Web.dll in mod mono web application bin

Tags: asp.net, assemblies, mod-mono

I'm migrating an asp.net web application from a 64bit Windows 2008R2 server running IIS 7.x onto a debian 6.06 running apache and mod mono. I'm getting the following error:

> Error 500: Could not load type
>   'System.Web.Configuration.HttpCapabilitiesProvider'

I was getting the same error for other assemblies such as `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` but i simply went to my .NET directory and copied that assembly into my bin folder which made the errors go away.

This is not working for the `System.Web.dll` **Anyone know why?**

When I copy the System.Web.dll into my bin directory in mod-mono I get the following error:

> Service Temporarily Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to
>   maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Comment: does anything show up in your ``/var/log/apache2/error_log`` ?

Comment: As an aside, you might want to be careful doing a blanket copy of Microsoft dlls distributed with Windows to a non-Windows machine - that might possibly violate the license agreement and expose you to legal liability.  But "I Am Not A Lawyer".

Comment: Also, it almost sounds like you are directly copying the compiled asp.net site to apache/mod-mono?  Have you tried compiling the site under mono and deploying it?